# Every derived table must have its own alias, i dont know how to fix

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont know how to fix this problem or why im getting it:
Every derived table must have its own alias.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba) AS `value_occurrence`  FROM udelezba_akcije
    INNER JOIN oseba ON udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba = oseba.Ime_osebe
    GROUP BY udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba
)
```

Comment: You add an alias, such as ` t` after the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias to it. A single letter at the end will do. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba) AS value_occurrence 
  FROM udelezba_akcije INNER JOIN oseba ON udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba = oseba.Ime_osebe 
  GROUP BY udelezba_akcije.Oseba_idOseba
) x
```

See the `x` I added? That's it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to add a table alias to the subquery ("derived table") in the `FROM` clause.  MySQL requires aliases for this purpose (some databases do not but most do).

I would just use aliases in general to simplify the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ua.Oseba_idOseba) AS `value_occurrence`
      FROM udelezba_akcije ua INNER JOIN
           oseba o
           ON ua.Oseba_idOseba = o.Ime_osebe
      GROUP BY ua.Oseba_idOseba
     ) uao;
```

The better way is to remove the subquery entirely.  You can write this as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ua.Oseba_idOseba) 
FROM udelezba_akcije ua INNER JOIN
     oseba o
     ON ua.Oseba_idOseba = o.Ime_osebe;
```

I don't know what your data looks like, but this might be more efficiently written as:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ua.Oseba_idOseba) 
FROM udelezba_akcije ua
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM oseba o
              WHERE ua.Oseba_idOseba = o.Ime_osebe
             );
```

And written like this, it is possible (depending on the data) that the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` can be replaced by `COUNT(*)`.